# Handle Exception at one place for api request in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am working on Xamarin forms and I need to send a lot of API request through out the project. I have made a global HTTP client object and using it every where. How can I handle HttpRequestException when Internet is down or server is not found. I am thinking of handling this exception at one place so that I don't repeat code in hundreds of places. Where and how Should I do it. In Xamarin.Forms I read we can not handle exception globally. I am thinking to handle all exceptions at one place and from there show an error page.

**Service Class**

```
 public partial class Service
    {
        private string BaseUrl { get; set; }
        private string AccessToken { get; set; }
        private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        public Service()
        {
        }
        public Service(string BaseUrl)
        {
            this.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        }
        public Service(string BaseUrl, string AccessToken)
        {
            this.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
            this.AccessToken = AccessToken;

        }

    }
}
```

**One Of Api Consumption Method**

```
public async Task<bool> ExternalLogin(string email)
        {
            bool UserAlreadyRegistered = false;
            bool IsUserRegistered = true;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(this.BaseUrl + "api/Account/UserInfo"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            };
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

            var UserInfo = await Client.SendAsync(request);
            if (UserInfo.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var response = await UserInfo.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var authenticationTicket = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
                if (authenticationTicket.Value<bool>("HasRegistered"))
                {
                    UserAlreadyRegistered = true;
                }
            }
            if (!UserAlreadyRegistered)
            {
                request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(this.BaseUrl + "api/Account/RegisterExternal"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                };
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("Email", email)
                        });
                request.Content = content;
                var authenticateResponse = await Client.SendAsync(request);
                if (!authenticateResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    IsUserRegistered = false;
                }
            }
            return IsUserRegistered;
        }
```

**Update After EvZ Ans**

Call To extension Method:

```
string result = await Task.Run(() => new Service(Settings.BaseUrl, Settings.AccessToken).Register(Model)).ExecuteAsyncOperation();
```

Extension Method:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<T> ExecuteAsyncOperation<T>(this Task<T> operation)
        {
            try
            {
                return await operation;
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your service to have the next methods (according to your needs):

```
async Task<T> Post<T>(string url, object body)
async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
```

Each of these methods should get a `HttpResponseMessage` that you should check for a success or failure.

Additionally you can introduce a `MyApi` class, that will consume the methods from your `Service` class in the next way:

```
async AuthenticationResult Authenticate() =>
await service.Post("http://myapi.com/token", new AuthenticationRequest { Username = "x", Password = "xxx"});
```

P.S.: Please note that `Service` is a very bad naming. It is totally unclear what a `Service` class is responsible for.
P.S.S.: Alternatively you can create an extension method for `Task` to wrap all api requests and to have a single try / catch.
Simple example:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> ExecuteAsyncOperation<T>(this Task<T> operation)
    {
        try
        {
            return await operation;
        }
        catch{ }
    }
}

var token = await apiService.Authenticate(string username, string password).ExecuteAsyncOperation();
```

Comment: which one would be the best way? any examples of that extension method you are talking about?

Comment: The best way will be the way that will suit you the most. Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: please look at the edit I made. Is this the correct way?